# Are there any respectful but strong words to tell people to move faster?

Tags: phrase-request, vocabulary

The pedestrian way that leads to the place where I live is not wide enough for people to walk abreast. But sometimes, some people with strong muscle were walking very slowly ahead because they were reading their iphones.

I am not sure whether it was due to culture difference or they looked down on their opposite gender, because some of them did not understand what I said, and they did not even move their legs when I said, "would you move please, sirs"? And they were just laughing.

Was it better to say, "move your body please" in that situation?
Is that strong enough?
How do you tell people to move faster?

Comment: Cultural context, please...?

Comment: "Move your body, please" is a strong and (in my opinion) not very respectful thing to say, despite the "please".  In a situation like this, I think it is **not so much the exact words you say as how you say them**. If possible, I would just say very loudly, "Excuse me, please" or "Excuse me, I need to get by."  Repeat it forcefully several times if necessary and make sure they have heard you.  If they persist in not moving, I think you are entitled to push past them while repeating, "Excuse me."  **But I warn you that this is an extremely culture-dependent answer.**

Comment: @stangdon - I agree with "Excuse me, I need to get by." Excellent way to word this. I'm not so sure about the pushing part, though.

Comment: "Pardon me, sir" or "I beg your pardon". Loud enough to ensure you are heard but not louder. If it doesn't work, "kindly let me pass" or "can I pass please?". These are all polite and assertive despite the "asking" language. "Move" sounds like an order and is impolite; in an emergency you might shout "move away!" but for asking to let you pass it's inappropriate.

Comment: I would just say "Excuse me, I'm in a hurry." That puts the focus of the "problem" on you, not them. (Not the reality, but it is polite.) Ultimately, if they don't pay attention there is little you can do.

Comment: The one I like the most and widely used: *excuse me! coming through!*

Comment: On the London tube, what usually happens is one says **excuse me** just before running ***through*** someone, and then **oh sorry** afterwards, in keeping with being in a rush some of the usual pleasantries are abandoned.  If your situation is happening with the same people every time, no amount of courtesy will help, you have a different problem. Does this happen when you are in a group or alone? Usually people will move out of the way even if they are on their phone.

Comment: I think running **through** someone would be rather unusual, at least for those of us who aren't ghosts.

Comment: Is this walkway really so narrow that you can't even pass even if someone tries to let you squeeze past? I wonder if you actually want to ask people to move *faster* (as the question is currently worded), or if you'd just like them to let you past.

Comment: I see some fine answers here but if you think the person doesn't move despite your numerous requests, I suggest you "accidentally" step your foot(with the shoes on) on the rear end of the shoe near the collar just above the heel (Normally heels _slightly_ protrude outwards in a side view of a shoe) which would result in their foot getting out of their shoes and they would naturally stop to wear it again and then you could somehow move past them saying "Sorry, my mistake". This isn't something evil to do  :)

Comment: If, in the USA or UK, you were shopping at a major retailer within two or three days of Christmas, you should fully expect not to get anywhere in the store quickly.

Comment: And I do not at all suggest the tactic mentioned by @Jony Agarwal. Anything physical these days can quickly escalate into a shoving match or worse. I really like the one by Subjunctive: *Excuse me. Coming through* but you have to have space to get by the slow pokes for that one to work well. Because if you are not actually in the process of moving past them, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written [elsewhere](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/69228/32) about our "elaborate codes for acknowledging and regretting the unhappy necessity of imposing burdens on our peers".

Anglo-American culture is intensely, almost pugnaciously individualistic. Except in an evident emergency, no one is felt to be entitled to **demand** a particular action of someone else, and we resent such demands, even by (or especially by!) people who **are** entitled to make them, like policemen or bosses.

Consequently, we rarely use frank imperatives like "move", "step aside", "let me pass", even softened by "please". If you look at the language suggested in the Comments you'll see a number of linguistic strategies for 'distancing' demands:

- introducing the demand with an acknowledgment that you're imposing on your addressees and intruding on their privacy (***Excuse me*** or ***I beg your pardon**)
- casting the demand as a questions and as a hypothetical (***Could*** you please move?, ***Would*** you let me pass?)
- casting the demand as a favor conferred by your addressees (*I'd be so grateful ... I need to get past ... **thank you!***)

(Any of these **can** of course be uttered in a tone and with a demeanour which negates the distance and the politeness, so you have to keep your voice friendly and apologetic, and suppress any vexation you actually feel.)

In your particular situation, these may accompany physical actions like actually pushing your way through the people blocking your way; as long as you perform those actions in a manner which makes it clear that you are trying to avoid unnecessary contact and force, people will not ordinarily take offense.

All of this assumes that your addressees are ordinary folk, eager to accommodate your need. There's always a chance that you will encounter self-centered Yahoos who think it's funny to impede others, or thugs looking for victims to intimidate and bully. But there's really no linguistic strategy to meet situations like that—as they say, "That's life in the big city".

Comment: Yes, there is clearly no rule for all situations . A reasonable rule of thumb is to try out a few different ways of saying *excuse me*, asking yourself how you would react if anyone said them to you. In these sorts of circumstances a little bit of charm and good humour can go a very long way. It is worth cultivating.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to make some assumptions starting from the phrase you used "I am not sure whether...they looked down on their opposite gender".

I'm going to assume this is exactly the case. To understand what's happening here, [you will need some background about racism and sexism in the U.S. and certain other English-speaking countries](http://www.incite-national.org/page/dangerous-intersections), as well as the nature of [interactions which some people call microaggressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microaggression_theory).  You will also need to know that many people [believe individual discrimination has been largely eliminated](http://thefederalist.com/2014/01/09/why-white-privilege-is-not-the-problem/), but based on my personal observations of many interactions, I believe this view is very pernicious and inaccurate.

With that background, it is reasonable to assume that the people blocking your way were disrespecting you on purpose.

Unfortunately, I don't have a simple recommendation how you can avoid these endemic societal maladies.  I could suggest you avoid saying "sir" (and especially "sirs" which is even more formal) to people blocking your path (in my city, a typical level of respect among strangers on the street is to say "excuse me" and push your way around them *without slowing down*).  I could suggest you avoid speaking in any way that might let others see you as weak.  But I'm not going to recommend any of this, because [I disagree with blaming the victim of discrimination](http://www.damemagazine.com/2014/12/09/we-always-blame-victim).  What I am going to recommend, is that you don't take it personally, but share your experiences with others in order to support wider understanding and building a society that has more equity and compassion.